# How to change the color of a button when a date value changes and also when a textbox value changes?

Tags: jquery, html, css, datepicker

I have a view which has number of textboxes and a datepicker with a button of gray color. When the textbox and datepicker value is changed, the color of the button becomes red and if I replace the new value of input with previews it becomes gray again.

My code (below) is working fine with the textbox but not with the datepicker:

```
$(".class Selector").each(function(){
  $(this).on('change blur keyup',function(){
    if(oldvalue of textbox1!=newvalue of textbox1){
      $("#button id ").css('backgroundcolor','red')
    }
    else if(oldvalue of textbox2!=newvalue of textbox2){
      $("#button id ").css('backgroundcolor','red')
     }
    else if(oldvalue of datepicker !=newvalue of datepicker){
      $("#button id ").css('backgroundcolor','red')
     }
    else {
      $("#button id ").css('backgroundcolor','gray')
    }
  });
});
```

My code runs incase of textbox values but it is not working on datepicker case

In this case `.on` fired first while I want to fire date picker on change first. When I click on date picker textbox , I always get new date undefined.

Any help please. Thanks.

Comment: Look at pub/sub and custom events.  Your code will get a lot simpler very quickly.

Comment: any code Chris Caviness

Comment: Can you provide jsfiddle?

Comment: Provide a minimal markup and code necessary to demo.

Answer (score 0):

Use the JQuery UI datepicker.
In JQuery UI datepicker has function, name onSelect, under this function you can add your code. For know more please click here.[enter link description here](http://www.script-tutorials.com/datepicker-jquery-ui/)